# WCF Works from internal network address but returns error when external

Tags: wcf

I'm going nuts here - I'm on my 6th day of trying to trouble shoot this and I'm loosing my mind.

Basically internally, the service works 100% as expected.  I create a "consume" client on my external test line and I go to test it and it returns with

```
"The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (multipart/related; type=\"application/xop+xml\"). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<HTML>
<HEAD>
<link rel=\"alternate\" type=\"text/xml\" href=\"http://myexternaladdress.com/FileUploadService.svc?disco\"/>
<STYLE type=\"text/css\">
#content{ FONT-SIZE: 0.7em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 30px}BODY{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white}P{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana}PRE{BORDER-RIGHT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BORDER-TOP: #f0f0e0 1px solid; MARGIN-TOP: -5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 5px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #f0f0e0 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e5e5cc}.heading1{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 26px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; MARGIN-LEFT: -30px; WIDTH: 100%; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-TOP: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #003366}.intro{MARGIN-LEFT: -15px}</STYLE>
<TITLE>
FileUploadService Service</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV id=\"co'."}
```

Basically this is all I got it has an issue with the disco `http://myexternaladdress.com/FileUploadService.svc?disco`

Here is my service .config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
            switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              >
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml"
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
  initializeData="C:\temp\WCFDiagnosticsExample.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="uploadDirectory" value="C:\temp\upload" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging
            logEntireMessage="true"
            logMalformedMessages="true"
            logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
            logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
            maxMessagesToLog="3000"
       />
    </diagnostics>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="applyAddressFilterModeBehavior"
             type="Test.Behaviors.ApplyAddressFilterModeBehaviorElement, Test.Behaviors, 
                 Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" name="myWCF.FileUploadService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="myWCF.IFileUploadService" bindingConfiguration="myBinding"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="FileUploadServiceBinding" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxReceivedMessageSize="99108864" maxBufferSize="65536" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
          <applyAddressFilterModeBehavior/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="204800000"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The only difference is when I come externally I add the service via my external address which comes through a load balancer and redirects to https and then sends the traffic to a specific server and port.  And I can even `.Open` my service fine. My error occurs when i call a method.  Can someone please tell me how to retrieve the full message not just 1024 characters or point out what i'm doing wrong?

I tried adding enabledhttps and httpsuri and that did not resolve the issue.

Thanks!  I owe a lot of points to who ever helps me solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

Binding of your service seems to use wsHttpBinding binding. What is the purpose of the binding called **FileUploadServiceBinding**? It seems that it is not using.

Your WCF service probably gets an exception. You can get the error detail if you add these lines into web.config file of your service host.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Critical, Error" propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add initializeData="c:\error.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
    <filter type="" />
  </add>
</sharedListeners>
```

After adding these lines in your web.config, execute your client application once more. If an exception occurs, the exception details write in **error.svclog** file. You can use the svclog util of the .Net Framework to inspect the error details.